# I am not getting uploaded files from browse button,how to solve it?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using below code:

```
Try
        Dim j As Integer = 0
        Dim hfc As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files
        Dim PathName As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To hfc.Count - 1
            Dim hpf As HttpPostedFile = hfc(i)

            If hpf.ContentLength > 0 Then
                Try
                    hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/F:\ImageUploaded\") & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName))
                Catch
                    PathName = Server.MapPath(hpf.FileName)
                    Session("PathName") = PathName
                End Try
            End If
        Next
    Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception

        Throw
    End Try
```

hfc.count is always getting zero value.how to solve this problem?

below is my fileupload control

```
< asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Are you sure with this tag selection?

Comment: you have this problem with `asp.net` and `vb.net` also?

Comment: Problem is with vb.net

Comment: @son Are you sure your `hfc`  HttpFileCollection variable is not empty ?